# How to find out what fork/original of a gem is installed on my system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

When I add `gem 'delayed_job'` to my gemfile, how do I know whether I am going to get 
[collectiveidea / delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [tobi / delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) ?

Also, is there some way to check among the list of gems I already have installed, as to which fork/location those gems were downloaded/installed from?

Ps. I am using RVM on Ubuntu, Bundler and Rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one way to tell which github fork or branch you are downloading from. For the delayed_job gem you are downloading from collectiveidea's branch. You can tell [on this page](https://rubygems.org/gems/delayed_job) where the homepage points to collectiveidea's github fork. The reason you can't tell which fork in particular is because rubygems aren't linked to github repositories. They are simply packages that are uploaded to the site. For all you know you could be downloading a gem from a copy of someone's local repository that isn't even published on the internet. You could also be downloading from an SVN repository instead of a Git repository. In general the rubygems.org site should give you some idea of how to find the source code for a gem though. Also, most github gems tag their commits with a version number so that you can tell which revision you are using by checking the github/git tags.

Comment: hmm? so the command `bundle install` gets the gems from rubygems.org? then what is the purpose of having the same thing on github also?

Comment: It's a way for authors to collaborate using a common repository and to make the source code more easily available to all. The rubygems.org site doesn't store source code, it just stores bundled .pkg files that are downloadable.

Comment: GitHub is also used for code besides gems, it is not linked to rubygems.org.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify git location you can use :git param:

```
gem "delayed_job", :git => "git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git"
gem "delayed_job", :git => "git://github.com/tobi/delayed_job.git"
```

[Read](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html) more about Gemfile

Answer (score 1):

The gemspec contains a `homepage` attribute, which often shows the source code repository. You can view a gemspec of a locally installed gem with:

```
gem spec delayed_job
```

View the homepage with:

```
gem spec delayed_job | grep homepage
```

That said, the gemspec does not always have the source repo.

To help solve this problem (and others), I wrote a gem called `gemdiff`. It does the gemspec inspection, and if that does not contain a github URL, it searches github for a match. It includes exceptions for gems like `delayed_job`, which is a fork of the original repository by tobi.

```
gem install gemdiff
gemdiff find delayed_job
=> http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job
```

More valuably, `gemdiff` will inspect your project's bundle and can show you the source code diff between the version of a gem you have installed and the highest version that can be installed, as determined by bundler.

https://github.com/teeparham/gemdiff